# How do I flag which recorded TV and media files I've watched?

Tags: windows-7, tv, windows-media-center

I have a load of TV which my Windows 7 Home Premium Media Center has recorded and a load of series which I've ripped from my own DVD's. I constantly find myself having to go back and re-watch the first minute or so of half a dozen episodes to work out where I got to.

Is there a simple way to flag which episodes I've watched?